# where is AWS ECS local kubeconfig file?

Tags: amazon-ecs

ubuntu 16.04 linux
AWSCLI aws-cli/1.14.62 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.13.0-38-generic botocore/1.9.15

I am using AWS CLI to crete ECS cluster.  It seems to create normally:
aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name aws-cluster
{
    "cluster": {
        "status": "ACTIVE", 
        "statistics": [], 
        "clusterName": "aws-cluster", 
        "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 0, 
        "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
        "runningTasksCount": 0, 
        "activeServicesCount": 0, 
        "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:885519253000:cluster/aws-cluster"
    }
}

**but i can't find where it is writing local kubeconfig file**.  this file
is needed so that local kubectl can connect to the ECS cluster.

other k8s installers write the file to ~/.kube/config, but AWS CLI does not seem to write anything in that directory.

Can you tell me **where ECS local config file is located**? Is there
a CLI command to download the kubernetes config file?

Answer (score 0):

after doing more research... this question was based on ECS which seems to be a previous generation AWS service which was a competitor to kubernetes but not the same as kubernetes. i think ECS was supposed to accept task which were created via AWS CLI (not kubectl) - so this question doesn't make sense for ECS.

AWS has a new service EKS which is coming online. EKS is supposed to be the AWS native form of kubernetes. when it is fully ready, i will try EKS - i assume it will use kubectl on the client side.